# Always Encrypted Feature in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have encrypted the table columns using the always encrypted feature in SQL server 2016.
But I have a problem when setting a value to a varaible inside a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE @Salesman AS NVARCHAR (max);
IF @SalesmanNumber > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Salesman = FirstName
        FROM   CommonContacts
        WHERE  CompanyNumber = @CompanyNumber
               AND ContactNumber = @SalesmanNumber;
    END
```

Give me this error

> Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@Salesman'

Note: The FirstName is an encrypted column

Comment: The decrypted FirstName value is available only in the client application since that's where values are encrypted/decrypted with AE (unless you are using secure enclaves, a SQL 2019 feature).

Comment: Thank you for your comment
I need to retrieving plaintext values stored in encrypted columns on a stored procedure

Comment: If were were able to decrypt the value in the proc, the plaintext value would not be "always encrypted".

Comment: That's means we cannot use encrypted columns inside a stored procedure.

Comment: A lot of columns are used inside a stored procedure, please do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Options I can think of are 1) upgrade to SQL 2019 and use secure enclaves or 2) encrypt columns using a method other than AE. Maybe someone else has other ideas.